# Dumbfounded declaring a variable in sql

Tags: sql, variables, declaration

I have searched across the board and the internet trying to see what I'm doing wrong. I have endlessly gotten the "Declare: syntax" error no matter where in the code I have moved the declaration. I've tried it with and without @ signs and semicolons thinking this was something different than C++. All the guides I've read say this should work so perhaps someone here can tell me what is wrong?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @clID INT;
CREATE TABLE CLAIM(claimID, repDate, lossDate, claimNo, claimStat);
INSERT INTO CLAIM VALUES(1, '2016-10-1', '2016-10-1', 1, 'Open');
INSERT INTO CLAIM VALUES(2, '2016-10-1', '2016-10-1', 2, 'Open');

CREATE TABLE EXPOSURE(expID, claimID, coverage, claimEx, expStat);
INSERT INTO EXPOSURE VALUES(1, 2, 'BI', 'U152', 'Open');
INSERT INTO EXPOSURE VALUES(2, 2, 'PD', 'U152', 'Open'); 

CREATE TABLE RESERVELINE(resLineID, expID, claimID, covID, IP);
INSERT INTO RESERVELINE VALUES(1, 1, 2, 'BI', 02);
INSERT INTO RESERVELINE VALUES(1, 3, 3, 'CDL', 01);

CREATE TABLE RESULTS(claimID);
COMMIT; 

INSERT INTO RESULTS
SELECT claimID FROM CLAIM WHERE repDate<'2016-10-3';
SELECT * FROM RESULTS;

--Must FIRST query first table with Date()
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: SQL Server? Oracle? Tag your post with the correct RDBMS

Comment: The attributes in your create statements don't have a datatype

Comment: Please supply some more information: 
what SQL-standard is this?
what is the exact error?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info its TransactSQL. As it turns out though I didn't need anything except for the SELECT statement. Thank you guys for your prompt responses.